# Generating a dynamic proxy that intercepts all methods of an object in Scala using macros

Tags: scala, dynamic, proxy, macros, intercept

I have several objects with different methods (without any traits/interfaces) and I'd like to intercept those methods in order to add them some kind of a debug feature. I think I can achieve that with macros in Scala 2.11.12. Macros seem to be quite powerful but not trivial at all.

The methods that I want to get intercepted can call among them, that's why I can't use a simple Proxy approach. I've also tried using AspectJ, but don't want to add any dependencies to my project if I can help it.

This is what I'm trying, but I don't know how to call the methods I'm trying to intercept.

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

object MacroProxy {
  def createProxy[T](original: T): T = macro createProxyImpl[T]

  def createProxyImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(original: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[T] = {
    import c.universe._
    val className = original.getClass.getSimpleName

    val m = weakTypeOf[T].members.iterator.toList
      .filter(m => m.isMethod).map(_.asMethod).map { m =>
        q"""override def  ${m.name} = $m"""
    }

    c.Expr {
      q"""new $className {  ..$m } """
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error

> missing argument list for method mymethod in class MyClass
> Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
> You can make this conversion explicit by writing `mymethod _` or `mymethod(_)` instead of `mymethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. nothing indicates that you need whitebox macros since the type is known from the beginning
2. what you do sounds weirdly similar to what ScalaMock does, so borrowing implementation from it might be easier than implementing something yourself
3. what you did is equal to :

   ```
   class Foo {
     def a(): Int = ...
     def b(a: String): Double = ...
   }
   new Foo {
     override def a = original.a
     override def b = original.b
   }
   ```

   You basically skipped on argument lists and compiler thinks you are trying to turn methods into functions through eta expansion (which wouldn't let you override). You'd have to do something like:

   ```
   val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
   tpe.members.iterator.toList
    .filter(m => m.isMethod).map(_.asMethod).map { m =>
        val name = m.name
        val params = m.typeSignatureIn(tpe).paramLists
        val arguments = params.map(_.map(_.name.toTermName))
        q"""override def $name($...params) = $original.$name(...$arguments)"""
    }
   ```

   Though it would be just the beginning:

   - to be able to call `new $className { ... }` you have to check if class doesn't require some constructor with parameters
   - you have to pay attention when to use `..` (to expand sequence of definitions/parameters/trees) and `...` (to expand sequence of sequences, which appear with every parameter list)
   - you'd have to check which symbols are public and which aren't
   - you'd have to remember about manually applying types, because type parameters aren't magically propagating themselves
   - you'd have to repeat all of that in Scala 3 since it has a completely new macro API and everything you would do here would be DOA in Scala 3

Basically, what you are trying to do is doable, but unless you want to support only most basic cases, this would be much more work than a single afternoon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question so well. I really appreciate all your comments. Regarding the comment about using ScalaMock: that's a library for testing ... wouldn't be weird to use it for other purpose? Besides, I'm not sure internal calls (from method a to method b) would get intercepted.

Comment: It would be weird to use mocking library in a production code, yes, but if you think about it you are basically describing spy objects, which forward all calls to the object while also keeping tabs on what was called and how. So instead of writing all that logic from scratch it would be easier to either use spies in prod code (which on its own should be a good reason to rethink if you actually need it) or look into ScalaMock or Mockito-Scala code and borrow this and that (while giving credit where credit is due!).